# Prototype DOM-traversal methods failing on HTML5 elements in IE < 9 using html5shiv

Tags: internet-explorer, html, dom, prototypejs

I'm using [html5shiv 1.6.2](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) (latest)  and Prototype v1.7 (latest).

So, html5shiv makes my `<article>`, `<section>` etc elements work nicely in IE < 9. They appear, I can style them etc. All good.

However, if I try to grab any such HTML5 elements using Prototype's DOM-traversal methods (e.g. `down()`, `up()`), then they always return `undefined` in IE8/IE7 (who cares about IE6?). For example:

```
<article id="foo">
    <div></div>
    <section></section>
    <ul id="abc123"></ul>
</article>
```

..and then..

```
var bar = $('foo').down('div'); // works
var baz = $('foo').down('section'); // undefined
```

..and..

```
var theArticle = $('abc123').up('article'); // undefined
```

Anyone experienced such woes? Solutions/workarounds?

Comment: HTML to reproduce: http://pastebin.com/TC1Dp5At

Comment: +1 for a well asked question. +1000000 for 'who cares about IE6'  :-)

Comment: BTW, the HTML5 elements all exist within the IE DOM tree in Developer Tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be down to a bug in the sizzlejs selector engine as coupled with Prototype 1.7, but it's fixed in later versions of sizzlejs. So, options are:

1. wait for next Prototype version (probably with newer sizzlejs)
2. go back to Prototype 1.6.x for now..

Comment: Andrew Dupont from Prototype core team confirms this will be fixed in 1.7.0.1, via an update of sizzlejs to the latest available version..